# Get class of forth cell adjacent to current cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to get class of fourth cell using `eq()` selector. Its working without `eq` selector like this  :

```
 alert($cell.closest( "td" ).next().next().next().attr("class"));
```

I tried using multiple variation of `eq()` but it's not working please help.
 None of the below are working.

```
 $cell = $(this);
 alert($cell.find( "td" ).eq(3).attr("class"));
 alert($cell.closest( "td" ).eq(3).attr("class"));
 alert($cell.( "td:eq(3)" ).attr("class"));
```

Comment: can you post the html??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the `eq` method work.

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.

As the `closest` method returns one element, `eq(3)`  returns an empty set in here. You can use the `nextAll` method for creating a set of next siblings. Then `eq(3)` will return the fourth element in that set:

```
$cell.closest("td").nextAll().eq(3).attr("class");
```

Please note that if `this` here refers to a `td` element then `closest('td')` does nothing.

Comment: it should be $cell.closest("td").nextAll().eq(2).attr("class"); for fourth cell class :)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar That can't be true, a set is zero-based and `eq(3)` returns the fourth element in the set. If the "fourth" element means the  third element after the `this` element, `eq(2)` is what you are looking for.